# Manipulating Data in Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

**Diagram:**

[image: Diagram of 4 tables combined]

**Query for join:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName , sh.DueDate, p.ProductID,p.ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Customer c 
  INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader sh
    ON c.CustomerID = sh.CustomerID 
  INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sd
    ON sh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
  INNER JOIN SalesLT.Product p
    ON sd.ProductID = p.ProductID
Order BY ListPrice Desc
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

**For desired output:**

1. What could be the add on to the existing query?
2. What would be the optimized way of doing this query ?
3. What would be the time and space complexity for Sub query and join?

Comment: Have you used Over Clause with Aggregate function? If not, you might want to check out it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain why Product IDs in desired result table have these values? I.e. why 794, 795, 793 and 956?

Comment: Always post SQL DDL (CREATE TABLE) statements, and sample INSERT statements. It *looks* like Christopher wants 5 products, each with the same list price. What's the logic behind showing only *one* of them in the output? Also, as a rule of thumb, build troublesome queries around the primary keys until you've got the data right. That is, include SalesOrderID, etc.

Comment: @Mike Aye Sr I thanks for advice. I was just trying to get my concepts straight. Its sample db Advenure Salesdb by msdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
    SELECT c.CustomerID
    , c.FirstName 
    , sh.DueDate
    , MAX(p.ProductID) ProductID
    ,p.ListPrice
    FROM SalesLT.Customer c 
      INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader sh
        ON c.CustomerID = sh.CustomerID 
      INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sd
        ON sh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
      INNER JOIN SalesLT.Product p
        ON sd.ProductID = p.ProductID
    GROUP BY
    , c.FirstName 
    , sh.DueDate
    , p.ListPrice

Order BY ListPrice Desc
```

Not that it makes much sense as a query, but I guess you wanted to know the approach? Probably you have a good answer by now, but it encourages us to put time into an answer if you tick an appropriate response, thanks